# Using jsPDF and html2canvas with es6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm trying to use jsPDF and html2canvas with es6.

I'm Importing html2canvas and jsPDF but getting an error on the addHTML
when I comment out the addHTML the pdf is generated.

any clue what is the problem?

Thanks.

> jspdf.debug.js:3754Uncaught Error: You need either https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas or https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js(…)jsPDFAPI.addHTML @ jspdf.debug.js:3754(anonymous function) @ index.js:12(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?V1.27.2:31546(anonymous function) @ bundle.js?V1.27.2:31547__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap f7845b2…:555fn @ bootstrap f7845b2…:86(anonymous function) @ bootstrap f7845b2…:578__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap f7845b2…:555(anonymous function) @ bootstrap f7845b2…:578(anonymous function) @ bootstrap f7845b2…:578

```js
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

doc.setFontSize(40);
doc.text(35, 25, "Paranyan loves jsPDF");

doc.addHTML(document.footer,function() {
     pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

```html
<footer>
 <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Would like to know if you ever solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Include the following script in index.html instead of the import in typescript file

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/1225:

jsPDF requires html2canvas to be on the window:

`window.html2canvas = html2canvas`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to calling `window.` you can also modify your import to this: `import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'`