# Working with jsPDF and html2canvas in a Vuejs project (without webpack)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jspdf, html2canvas

I am working on a functionality in a Vuejs project, by which by clicking on a button, the user can export a pdf which will contain certain Vuejs components. All went smooth up to a point. I npm installed the 2 packages, jsPDF and html2canvas (which is a dependency).
I added jsPDF to the component like so:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf'
```

The function that gets triggered on button click is:

```
exportpdf() {
    let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'a4')
    pdf.addHTML(this.$refs.userinfo, function() {
         pdf.save('web.pdf')
    })
}
```

When the function was triggered on button click, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: You need either https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas or https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js...
```

And so, I got to this issue here:
[Using jsPDF and html2canvas with es6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708456/using-jspdf-and-html2canvas-with-es6) which explains that jsPDF requires html2canvas to be on the window. But this is just a huge no no in Vuejs (see article here):
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

So, inspired by this article, I added the html2canvas package to main.js:

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'
...
Vue.use(html2canvas)
```

Now, when the function is triggered I get this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Provided element is not within a Document
```

I also tried with document.querySelector('#userinfo') - same result. So now I consider myself officially stuck - any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

html2canvas is not a Vue plugin, so you cannot call use(...) on it.

You can make your own plugin though.

```js
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas'

let MyPlugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    window.html2canvas = html2canvas
  }
}

// ...
Vue.use(MyPlugin)
```

I am not really sure why you are opposed to `window.html2canvas = html2canvas` if another library needs it.

Comment: OK, I understand and indeed, I cannot use it (I'm new to Vuejs). But the whole idea here was to avoid assigning html2canvas to the window object. I don't see how this solves the issue, only that it wraps the assignment in a plugin.

Comment: You seemed to want to 'encapsulate the fix' code in a plugin per your example and external reference...  If jsPDF expects a global window object, there is nothing wrong with assigning it.  This is not a 'Vue' issue at all.